# Moved wordpress from localhost to live and wp-admin shows white screen

Tags: wp-admin, localhost, local-installation

Hi I developed a website in wordpress on my localhost then moved it to a live server. Everything is working fine except wp-admin. When I go to domain/wp-admin it shows a white screen. Yet when I go to domain/wp-login.php it allows me to login to the admin. Also if I try to create new post or update any settings it keeps showing a blank white screen, yet when refreshed has saved the settings/added the post etc.
The site is www.nuvogadgets.com.

Any ideas? 
Thanks!

Comment: Hi ... this is a very common question / problem on here and there is a dedicated page on the Codex on how to move WordPress http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress

Comment: It sounds like you might have a problem with your functions.php file. I would suggest removing the last `?>` in the file.

Comment: @PaulElliot: White screen = no debugging info.Add that to your wp-config.php file (details about WP debugging in Codex).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you say moved WordPress, what do you mean exactly,

- Did you copy your entire WordPress installation from your localhost to your remote server without installing WordPress first on your destination host?
- Did you export your SQL database from localhost then import it to your remote server?
- Did you install WordPress on your remote server before copying your theme folder across?

It's likely that the parameters found under `Settings -> General` for both,

- WordPress Address (URL)
- Site Address (URL)

Are both incorrect and still pointing to your localhost environment.

You should install WordPress from scratch on your remote server prior to copying over your theme instead of copying your entire WordPress folder from your localhost.

Otherwise if you want, login to your MySQL manager (likely phpMyAdmin) and edit the entries for,

- WordPress Address (URL)
- Site Address (URL)

Under the `wp_options` table.

As suggested by **Damien** (in comments), there is of course a whole section on the Codex dedicated to this topic,

http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress

In particular the following section title [**"If you forget to change the locations"**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress#If_you_forget_to_change_the_locations), relates directly to the WordPress Address URL and Site Address URL mentioned above.

Comment: Hi there ... you might like to include a link to the Codex page http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress   ... also I think the OP can't get to /wp-admin  so they would have to login in via PHPMyAdmin.

Comment: Yes, I like. I should clarify that I recommending to login via **phpMyAdmin**, not via `wp-admin`, that's just a reference of where those parameters of normally held - just to give some context. Though, the section I link to within the **Moving WordPress** Codex page shows an alternative using `update_options` to reset the URLs. Thanks for reminding me about the link, a must read for anyone moving WP for the first time.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I copy over my WordPress to a new location I always take over my database modifier php script:

```
<?php

$database_host = '';
$database_user = '';
$database_pass = '';
$database_name = '';

$replacement_values = array( 'http://oldurl' => 'http://newurl' );
$text_fields = array( 'char', 'text', 'varchar' );

$mysql = mysql_connect( $database_host, $database_user, $database_pass );
if ( !$mysql ) {
    die( 'Could not connect: ' . mysql_error() );
}

$mysql_database = mysql_select_db( $database_name, $mysql );
if ( !$mysql_database ) {
    die( 'Can\'t select database: ' . mysql_error() );
}

$tables_result = mysql_query( 'SHOW TABLES' );
while ( $tables_row = mysql_fetch_row( $tables_result ) ) {
    foreach ( $tables_row as $table ) {
        $columns_result = mysql_query( 'SHOW COLUMNS FROM ' . $table );
        while ( $columns_row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $columns_result ) ) {
            $column = $columns_row[ 'Field' ];
            $type = $columns_row[ 'Type' ];
            foreach ( $text_fields as $text_field_type ) {
                if ( strpos( $type, $text_field_type ) !== false ) {
                    echo '<p>' . $type . ' - ' . $column . ':' . $table . '</p>';
                    foreach ( $replacement_values as $replace => $replacement ) {
                        $replace_query = sprintf( 'UPDATE %s SET %s = REPLACE(%s, \'%s\', \'%s\')', $table, $column, $column, $replace, $replacement );
                        mysql_query( $replace_query );
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

mysql_free_result( $columns_result );
mysql_free_result( $tables_result );
mysql_close ( $mysql );

?>
```

You can change the values here:

`$replacement_values = array( 'http://oldurl' => 'http://newurl' );`

to what you want to replace.

Comment: What about the serialized strings? Next time use this: http://interconnectit.com/124/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/ ;)